# preseve line breaks in sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I am using sqlite3 in nodejs with knex.
When I select a string that have line breaks, I get a continuous text.
Example :
My string in the sqlite file :

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I get :

```
aaabbbccc
```

How can I get the the string unchanged ?

Comment: It is possible that there is a "\n" between "aaa" and "bbb" ; and another "\n" between "bbb" and "ccc", but just your display interface fails to render it on screen. (that is quite common). Please tell us what interface you are using to display the result 'aaabbbccc'.

Comment: Thank you @KenLee . I forget to mention that it's Electron.

Comment: If I remember correctly , Electron uses JavaScript. Hence please use a javascript function say like replace(/\n/g, "<br />") to replace all the carriage return characters to "<br>" so that you can see the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @KenLee. 
This worked for me :
 replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />')

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me : `replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />')`

Comment: good to note that you have fixed the problem. Have a nice day.